# Парсер на python. Как скипнуть одну подфункцию в функции

Tags: python, selenium

Всем привет. Пишу парсер на python и столкнулся с проблемой:
У меня есть функция, которая заполняет анкету(Город, улица, фамилия, имя, отчество, телефон и тп). Выглядит примерно так:

```
def fill_card(self):
    self.city()
    self.region()
    self.surname()
    self.name()
```

city, region, surname, name также являются функциями и объявлены выше.
**Суть проблемы**: Мне не всегда нужно заполнять все поля, иногда хватает города и фамилии. А плодить еще кучу функций по типу fill_card_without_region я не хочу. Возможно, есть какой-то параметр или 'костыль', чтобы просто в скобках указать какое поле не нужно заполнять, пропустить его. Есть идеи?

Comment: а условия пропуска какие?

Answer (score 0):

Так:

```
def fill_card(self, include_region=True, include_city=True):
    if include_city:
        self.city()
    if incude_region:
        self.region()
    self.surname()
    self.name()
```

Пользуемся:

```
# полное заполнение
fill_card()

# без заполнения региона
fill_card(incude_region=False)
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Все работает как нужно